# Can one render crossing 3d arrows in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, 3d

I need a diagram with several arrows, some passing in front of others. So far the only thing I could do is to draw them with Mathematica and import as an image. An example of this: https://mathoverflow.net/q/236707/41291

[image]

As you see, this is far from satisfactory in many respects.

Can something like this be drawn with TikZ? Or maybe there is some other package better suited for such things?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `tikz-cd` with the `crossing over` option. You just have to make sure you place the arrows in the right order (from back to front).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=12mm, column sep=6mm, outer sep=0pt, arrow style=tikz, 
    arrows={-latex, semithick, blue!60!black}, crossing over clearance=5pt]
x_1\arrow[rrrrrr]\arrow[ddr] &[3mm]&[-1mm]&[-2mm]&[-2mm]&[-1mm]&[3mm] x_2\arrow[ddddd]\arrow[dlll]\\
 &&& c_2\arrow[red, ulll]\arrow[dr]\\[5mm]
 & c_1\arrow[ddrr] &&& c_{23}\arrow[red, lll]\arrow[dr]\arrow[uullll]\\[-10mm]
 && c_{12} &&& c_3\arrow[red, uuur]\\
 &&&c_{13}\arrow[red, dlll]\arrow[uur]\\
 x_0\arrow[uuuuu]\arrow[rrrrrr] &&&&&& x_3\arrow[ulll]\arrow[uul]
\arrow[crossing over, from=6-1, to=1-7]
\arrow[crossing over, from=4-3, to=5-4]
\arrow[crossing over, from=2-4, to=3-2]
\arrow[crossing over, from=1-1, to=6-7]
\arrow[crossing over, from=5-4, to=4-6]
\arrow[crossing over, from=4-3, to=2-4]
\arrow[red, crossing over, from=4-6, to=2-4]
\arrow[crossing over, from=3-2, to=4-3]
\arrow[red, crossing over, from=4-6, to=4-3]
\arrow[red, crossing over, from=4-3, to=6-1]
\arrow[red, from=3-2, to=6-1]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow that's beautiful! Except in some cases it might be tricky to figure out what is behind what. For example, in my case the octahedron (with vertices labeled by indexed `c`s) must be entirely inside the tetrahedron with vertices `x_0`, `x_1`, `x_2`, `x_3`. Supposedly the arrow from `x_0` to `x_2` must be behind everything, then from `c_{23}` to `x_1`, but also I believe some edges are missing - e. g. there must be complete octahedron with "inner face" `c_1 - c_{12} - c_2` and "outer face" `x_0 - x_1 - x_2`, and I do not quite see how to order all their edges...

Comment: I find this one very much more legible thant the one you produced in your question.

Comment: @SebGlav absolutely!